# Range out of order in character class in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I don't know why my regex is incorrect:

```
var domain = "google\.com\.br";
var reEmail = new RegExp("^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@" + domain + "$");
```

I need this to validate an email. Example below: `reEmail.test("contact@google.com.br");`

I get this error:

**Range out of order in character class**

Comment: Use a regex literal: `/^([A-Za-z0-9_\-.])+@/`!!!

Answer (score 140):

Because you create the RegExp using a String the `_\-\.` becomes `_-.`  and that is the invalid range.
(It is a range from `_`  to `.` and that is not correct)

You need to *double escape* it:

```js
new RegExp("^([A-Za-z0-9_\\-\\.])+@" + domain + "$");
```

That way the `\\` becomes a `\` in the String and then is used to escape the `-`in the RegExp.

**EDIT:**

If you create RegExp by String it is always helpful to log the result so that you see if you did everything right:

e.g. your part of the RegExp

```js
console.log("^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@");
```

results in:

```
^([A-Za-z0-9_-.])+@
```

Comment: On a side note, a quick way to handle this is, if you need to allow a `-` as a valid character in your character group, always place it as either the first or last character in the group (e.g., `[-a-zA-Z0-9 _]` or `[a-zA-Z0-9 _-]`).  Regex is smart enough to know that you are not specifying a range with that character, if it is in those positions (without needing to escape it with a slash).

Comment: @talemyn Sure thats true. Personally i prefer to escape it (and also set this into our coding guideline) because it has a special meaning.

Comment: This should be accepted answer. nice addition by @talemyn also

Comment: @talemyn That's a very cool trick.  However, for any project that involves more than one developer and one day, it is possible that the next developer (including yourself tomorrow) might not know/remember this trick! So, when they want to add a new character (say `#`) to the range they might just put it at the beginning (i.e. `[#-a-zA-Z0-9_]`) and it will take the whole company three days to figure out why it's now broken!

Comment: @Aidin - Going to have to disagree with you there.  It's not a trick, it's simply one of the potential behaviors of dashes in the JavaScript flavor of regex . . . really no different than understanding how a slash behaves when you use it like this: "\" vs this: "\\".  Now I'm not saying that it's one of the better known behaviors, but just because a lot of people don't know about a feature doesn't mean that you shouldn't use it . . . that's how more people eventually learn about it.

Answer (score 0):

this is because RegEx works with STRINGS not numbers, so for 2 digit number ranges like: 1 to 16, you CAN NOT use  /[1-16]/ = ERROR NOT A VALID RANGE

You need to do this:

```
/([1-9]|1[0-6])/;
```

NOTE: in the above you also need to include  VALUE < 17, otherwise regex will match anything that has 6 in it, like 26, 36 etc., as well as other number that you don't want.

You can also go this route:

```
/1|2|3...|15|16/
```

in the above you need to replace ... with |4|5.. etc.

See here for REGEX for Ranges: https://3widgets.com/

alternatively, try to use FOR LOOP to filter or test stuff out.