# How can I use a regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I found a regex at regexlib and I want to use it in a simple string validation using javascript.

The regex is:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$
```

But I tried to use it like this:

```
mystring = 'hello@world.com';
re = '^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$';

    if(mystring.match(re)){
     console.log('true');
    }
```

And I got this console error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: //^([a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+)@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9-]+.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(]?)$/: Range out of order in character class
```

What's wrong?
I'm not a professional.. This is just a simple project I'm trying to do in my free time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Range out of order in character class in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727884/range-out-of-order-in-character-class-in-javascript)

Comment: When I 'try to follow this another post solution I get another error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing it like this:

```
var re = new RegExp('^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\\]?)$');
```

In javascript the `\` character escapes the string so that's why it's not working. In the previous example I just doubled them up and that should work. Here it is in practice:

```js
mystring = 'hello@world.com';
re = new RegExp('^([a-zA-Z0-9_\\-\\.]+)@((\\[[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+\\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\\]?)$');

if (mystring.match(re)) {
  console.log('true');
}
```

You could also try a RegEx literal like this:

```
var re = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
```

Here is that in practice:

```js
var mystring = 'hello@world.com';
var re = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;

if (mystring.match(re)) {
  console.log('true');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To define a RegEx you need to use `/` and not `'`.

```js
mystring = 'hello@world.com';
re = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;

    if(mystring.match(re)){
     console.log('true');
    }
```